# how to display data in one record in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, datatable

when I display the data from the database, I find the error that the data is repeated. I want to display data in only one record based on the same siswa_id

This is the table from My database:

[image]

This is result :

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  No   |  Nama Siswa   |  NIS      | Kelas   | Jul  | Agu  | Sep |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1    |Iwan Setiawan  |161710044  |10 RPL   | OK   |  X   |  X  |
|  2    |Iwan Setiawan  |161710044  |10 RPL   | X    | OK   |  X  |
|  3    |Iwan Setiawan  |161710044  |10 RPL   | X    |  X   |  OK |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It should be like this :

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  No   |  Nama Siswa   |  NIS      | Kelas   | Jul  | Agu  | Sep |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1    |Iwan Setiawan  |161710044  |10 RPL   | OK   |  OK  |  OK |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is My Controllers :

```
public function RekapPembayaran()
{
    if($this->M_login->logged_id())
    {   
        $data['judul'] = 'Rekap Pembayaran SPP';

        $data['rekap'] = $this->M_admin->rekap_pembayaran();

        $this->load->view('admin/pembayaran-spp/rekap-pembayaran', $data);
    } else {
        //jika session belum terdaftar, maka redirect ke halaman login
        redirect("login");
    }
}
```

This is My Models :

```
public function rekap_pembayaran()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_siswa');
    $this->db->join('tbl_pembayaran', 'tbl_siswa.id_siswa=tbl_pembayaran.siswa_id');
    $this->db->join('tbl_rombel', 'tbl_siswa.rombel_id=tbl_rombel.id_rombel');      
    $this->db->order_by('nama_rombel, nama_siswa', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

This is My Views :

```
<tbody>
    <?php $no = 1;
        foreach ($rekap as $data) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->nama_siswa; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->nis; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->nama_rombel; ?></td>
                <?php if($data->bulan_dibayar == 7){ 
                    echo '<td><j class="btn btn-primary"><b>OK</b></j></td>';
                }else{ 
                    echo '<td><j class="btn btn-danger"><b>X</b></j></td>';
                }?>
                <?php if($data->bulan_dibayar == 8){ 
                    echo '<td><j class="btn btn-primary"><b>OK</b></j></td>';
                }else{ 
                    echo '<td><j class="btn btn-danger"><b>X</b></j></td>';
                }?>
                <?php if($data->bulan_dibayar == 9){ 
                    echo '<td><j class="btn btn-primary"><b>OK</b></j></td>';
                }else{ 
                    echo '<td><j class="btn btn-danger"><b>X</b></j></td>';
                }?>
            </tr>
            <?php $no++;
        } ?>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you, Change the query. Assuming you DB is like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `prueba`.`test` 
(`id_pembayaran` INT NOT NULL , 
`siswa_id` INT NOT NULL , 
`siswa_descrip` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , 
`bulan_dibayar` INT NOT NULL , 
`tanggal_bayar` DATE NOT NULL ) 
ENGINE = InnoDB; 
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD PRIMARY KEY( `id_pembayaran`); 

INSERT INTO `test` (`id_pembayaran`, `siswa_id`, `siswa_descrip`, `bulan_dibayar`, `tanggal_bayar`) VALUES 
('4', '2', 'Iwan Setiawan ', '7', '2021-07-14'), 
('5', '2', 'Iwan Setiawan ', '8', '2021-07-15'), 
('6', '2', 'Iwan Setiawan ', '9', '2021-07-16');
```

Then you query should be:

```
SELECT t.`siswa_id`, t.`siswa_descrip`,
(select  IF(t2.`bulan_dibayar` = 7, "OK", "X") from test t2 where t2.id_pembayaran = t.id_pembayaran)as 'JUL',
(select  IF(t2.`bulan_dibayar` = 7, "OK", "X") from test t2 where t2.id_pembayaran = t.id_pembayaran)as 'AUG',
(select  IF(t2.`bulan_dibayar` = 7, "OK", "X") from test t2 where t2.id_pembayaran = t.id_pembayaran)as 'SEP'
FROM `test` t 
group by  t.`siswa_id`
```

So, your model should look like:

```
public function rekap_pembayaran()
{  
    $sql = '     SELECT t.`siswa_id`, t.`siswa_descrip`, 
                (select  IF(t2.`bulan_dibayar` = 7, "OK", "X") from test t2 where t2.id_pembayaran = t.id_pembayaran)as 'JUL',
                (select  IF(t2.`bulan_dibayar` = 7, "OK", "X") from test t2 where t2.id_pembayaran = t.id_pembayaran)as 'AUG',
                (select  IF(t2.`bulan_dibayar` = 7, "OK", "X") from test t2 where t2.id_pembayaran = t.id_pembayaran)as 'SEP'
                FROM `test` t 
                group by  t.`siswa_id`
           ';              
    
    $query  =   $this->db->query($sql); 
    
    if($query->num_rows()>0)  {
        return $query->result();        
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }          
}
```

Comment: yes, that's true if it takes only three months. but here I take twelve months (January - December). So the query condition does not take only "7", but here there is "1" for "Jan", "2" for "Feb", "3" for "Mar" and so on.

Comment: In that case, You should put twelve conditions.

Comment: yes I have added, but for the other "siswa_descrip", the value will still be "x" even though we have added it

Comment: solved. I use the max case statement for the query. this is the query:

SELECT siswa_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bulan_dibayar = 1 THEN 'OK' END) AS JAN,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bulan_dibayar = 2 THEN 'OK' END) AS FEB,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bulan_dibayar = 3 THEN 'OK' END) AS MAR,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bulan_dibayar = 4 THEN 'OK' END) AS APR,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bulan_dibayar = 5 THEN 'OK' END) AS MEI,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bulan_dibayar = 6 THEN 'OK' END) AS JUN,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bulan_dibayar = 7 THEN 'OK' END) AS JUL,
       etc ..
FROM tbl_pembayaran
GROUP BY siswa_id